# I don’t use maven, spring or hibernate, just simple web dynamic app

Tags: java, sql, eclipse

Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`.

I am updating mysql server and workbench and now I lost connection in all applications in my workspace.

SQL Server is version 8.0.15.
I put it connector8.0.15.jar in all applications but it does not work.

Comment: this might be a good moment to start using maven (or another dependency management tool). "it does not work" -> can you be more clear on that part?

Comment: Hello. Welcome to SO. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sql server is 8.0.15 > you mean MySQL?

Comment: i use mysql 8.0.15

Comment: when i try to sign in in application in output just writes that message com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class iscom.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'.

Answer (score 0):

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class DBConnectionManager {

public DBConnectionManager () {}

```
private static Connection connection;

public static String driverClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
public static String connURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";

private static String user = "root";
private static String password = "root";


public static Connection getConnection() {
    try {

        if(connection == null) {

                Class.forName(driverClass);

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL, user, password);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return connection;
} // this is my connectionManager class, i have connector8.0.15.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Your connection statement should look like this：

```
public static String connURL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/work?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&serverTimezone=GMT%2B8&useSSL=false";
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn =(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(connURL ,"root", "123");
```

The content behind the connURL may vary from region to region.